# Is it not possible to include source files from multiple different parent directories in a jar?

Tags: java, jar

In [a blog](http://javahowto.blogspot.com/2006/07/something-you-may-not-know-about-jar_06.html) about command `jar`:

> It is not possible to include source files from multiple different parent directories. But you
>   can always first copy them into a common parent directory. Jar task in Apache Ant is more flexible
>   and can accommodate almost all use cases.

But why can I include two .class files under different parent directories?

```
$ jar -cf test.jar ../WordCount.class ./Temp.class
$ jar -tf test.jar
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
WordCount.class
Temp.class
```

What does the quote mean actually, if I misunderstand it?

Comment: I have no idea what the author is trying to say there. Unless the author means you can only pass one argument to `-C`. Which was the topic of 11 and 12.

Comment: I think the author is simply wrong. The article is also *ancient*, so why are you reading it? You should find something newer if you want to learn things that are currently relevant.

Comment: @Andreas Because I googled some questions using jar, it leads me to the blog, which answers my questions very well, and I haven't found another source addressing my questions. So I have trust on it. If it is wrong, can you point out what is correct instead?

Comment: "Since it *is* possible to include source files from multiple different parent directories, please ignore this paragraph."